How can I make Bridge-to-Kubernetes proxy an HTTPS service?
I am trying to get Bridge to Kubernetes to work with an Admission Webhook that is deployed to my cluster (a Rancher Desktop install running a K3S instance on my developer desktop.) Admission Webhooks are required to use HTTPS, so the Service is an ASP.NET application configured with a self-signed certificate, exposing ports 80 and 443.
Everything works within the cluster: the HTTPS requests are sent by the Admission Controller and the service logs show it responding. I can also wget from a busybox pod and get a response over HTTP and HTTPS.
When I configure Bridge to Kubernetes (selecting the https launch profile) the debugger launches and attaches successfully, I can make a request to the service (HTTP and HTTPS) using its local port. When I try to make a request to the service within the cluster using my busybox pod over HTTP, I can see the request succeeds and I get a redirect (407) to the HTTPS endpoint. Making the equivalent request over HTTPS I get the following:
/ # wget https://my-webhook.default.svc/review
Connecting to my-webhook.default.svc (10.43.228.214:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
wget: got bad TLS record (len:0) while expecting handshake record
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer

I can see the following logs generated by the reverse proxy:
2024-08-02T15:03:40.7630072Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | ReversePortForwardConnector on port 8081 accepted incoming request as stream 3.
2024-08-02T15:03:40.7635073Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | AgentHub connnected for 8081, id 3
2024-08-02T15:03:40.7637538Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | ReversePortForwardConnector.HookupStreamData ReadAsync 3 returns 144 bytes.
2024-08-02T15:03:40.7638315Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | AgentHub received for 8081, id 3, size 144
2024-08-02T15:03:42.7868736Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | AgentHub disconnect for 8081, id 3\nOperation context: <json>{"clientRequestId":"637901ec-192a-4556-b8fc-316523d2cf56","correlationId":"ca347131-affb-4b7f-925c-f0f81c400c28:19949ee2af29:c060342eca4b","requestId":null,"userSubscriptionId":null,"startTime":"2024-08-02T14:59:09.2912973+00:00","userAgent":"RemoteAgent/1.0.0.0","requestHttpMethod":null,"requestUri":null,"version":"1.0.0.0","requestHeaders":{},"loggingProperties":{"ApplicationName":"RemoteAgent","DeviceOperatingSystem":"Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023","Framework":".NET 7.0.19","ProcessId":1,"TargetEnvironment":"Production"}}</json>
2024-08-02T15:03:42.7871167Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | PortForwardConnector.Disconnect 3
2024-08-02T15:03:42.7872048Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | AgentHub closed for 8081, id 3
2024-08-02T15:03:42.7877971Z | RemoteAgent | TRACE | ReversePortForwardConnector.StartReceiveDataAsync exception 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled.' when invoking handler. Close.

I get no logs produced in my debugging client. The Kestrel server doesn't even log an incoming connection for the HTTPS attempt.
What do I need to do to enable this HTTPS connection to work? What could be the problem? What else can I do to diagnose further?

What happens when you make the wget request with wget --no-check-certificate?

the self-signed certificate used by your ASP.NET application is correctly configured and trusted by the Bridge to Kubernetes and the Kubernetes environment. ??? maybe you need to add trusted store cert
port forwarding configuration for HTTPS is correctly set up in Bridge to Kubernetes. ??? ---> set up to forward requests to the correct local ports (e.g., 8081 for HTTP and 8443 for HTTPS).
reverse proxy is accepting requests but failing to establish a connection || tls configuration ???
network || firewall issues???
THERE ARE A LOT, I highly suggest debugging steps:
Use tools like curl or openssl to test the HTTPS connection locally to see if you encounter any specific errors, the logging verbosity of both Bridge to Kubernetes and your ASP.NET application to get more detailed information about the requests and responses, check the Bridge to Kubernetes configuration, including launch profiles and port forwarding settings, to ensure everything is set up correctly for HTTPS traffic.
I hope this helps for you.
Local Machine Testing
curl -v https://localhost:8443/review --insecure
HTTPS Testing
openssl s_client -connect my-webhook.default.svc:443
Redirect Testing (HTTP && HTTPS Supported)
curl -v http://localhost:8080/review

curl -v http://my-webhook.default.svc/review ##another option if fails, if you get one of redirect response that means fine.

I hope this works for you, if not try to provide more logging work to here :)

Whilst these are broadly useful suggestions, they're all things that I have covered in the question. You can see a wget request's output, plus the logs generated by the reverse-proxy.
